# Static cards won't flip when "flip" function called

Tags: javascript, css

I have been trying for hours to get my playing cards to flip when the player clicks on them. When the eventListener is fired it should run the `flip` function which toggles between the front/backsides of a card. What am I doing wrong?

```js
const playingCards = document.querySelectorAll('.playing-cards');

function flipCard(){;
    this.classList.toggle("flip")
}

playingCards.forEach((card) => card.addEventListener("click", flipCard));
```

```css
.playing-cards{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.playing-cards .flip{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.front-card{
    background-color: aqua;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
.back-card{
    background-color: greenyellow; 
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.front-card,
.back-card{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<div class="memory-game">
    <div class="playing-cards">
        <div class="front-card">A</div>
        <div class="back-card"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="playing-cards">
        <div class="front-card">B</div>
        <div class="back-card"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="playing-cards">
        <div class="front-card">a</div>
        <div class="back-card"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="playing-cards">
        <div class="front-card">b</div>
        <div class="back-card"></div>
    </div>


</div>


<body>
    <script src=index.js></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer derived from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_flip_card.asp)

```js
const playingCards = document.querySelectorAll('.playing-cards');

function flipCard() {
  this.classList.toggle("flip")
}

playingCards.forEach((card) => card.addEventListener("click", flipCard));
```

```css
/* The flip card container - set the width and height to whatever you want. We have added the border property to demonstrate that the flip itself goes out of the box on hover (remove perspective if you don't want the 3D effect */
.memory-game {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  perspective: 1000px; /* Remove this if you don't want the 3D effect */
}

/* This container is needed to position the front and back side */
.playing-cards {
display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  cursor: pointer;/*clickable-cursor*/
}

/* Do an horizontal flip when you move the mouse over the flip box container */
.playing-cards.flip {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

/* Position the front and back side */
.front-card, .back-card {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Safari */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

/* Style the front side (fallback if image is missing) */
.front-card {
  background-color: aqua;

  color: black;
}

/* Style the back side */
.back-card {
  background-color: greenyellow;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="memory-game">
  <div class="playing-cards">
    <div class="front-card">A</div>
    <div class="back-card"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="playing-cards">
    <div class="front-card">B</div>
    <div class="back-card"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="playing-cards">
    <div class="front-card">a</div>
    <div class="back-card"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="playing-cards">
    <div class="front-card">b</div>
    <div class="back-card"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Edit: *Added* *cursor effect*

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I want the back of the card (it has a green background) to flip to the front so the blue is hidden when the function is called.

Comment: so ```.back-card``` should appear when function called

Comment: @Carminos updated answer